# Why does XChat always open only partially maximized?

Tags: 12.04, unity, xchat

When I start Xchat, I note the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom edge of the window is covered by some other thing (in this case, it's firefox status bar, but if I have no other window opened, I see my desktop background in that position), so I reduce it with the maximize button on top left:

[image]

Finally I maximize it again and obtain the wanted behaviour:

[image]

Is this a bug or can I adjust it in any way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the verification was made for 12.04. A recent update solved the issue for me. Now I'm running `1:0.30.0~git20110821.e2a400-0.2ubuntu4.1`

Answer (score 1):

It's been annoying me too :).  It's a [bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1016292) which is fixed in Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal) and will be fixed in 12.04 (requires verification).